# Visibility animation of BottomNavigationBar(Android) is somehow not so UI Friendly

Tags: flutter

A difference in the visibility animation of `StatusBar` and `BottomNavigationBar` is perceptible.

All I did was

```
 onTap:(){
    makeItFullScreen
        ? SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])
        : SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
           [SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);
    makeItFullScreen = !makeItFullScreen;
}
```

The flickering of that particular part(bottom) of the screen needs to be fixed I guess.

Most of us might not have noticed this because we usually use the white(default) background of our `Scaffold`.

P.S I tested it on Emulator and on an actual device.

[image: The GIF]

Comment: Cross-link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21212

Comment: I am the same guy :p I posted this so if someone else googles it, he can find the solution too. :)

Comment: I know and I added links so when someone finds one he also finds the other ;-) It's unlikely all helpful comments will be posted on both.

Comment: Haha, thanks :) I was goonna add the link in my question but was afraid if someone downvotes it (marking it as redundant)

Comment: I think it's a good questions. No need to be afraid.

Comment: Ok, but what is your question here? This is a Q-A site

Comment: check the bottom of the screen, found the problem? (it's the flickering of the screen, do you have any solution for this?)